# jqPlot data renderer with multiple plots

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jqplot

I have multiple plots, and, in line with the method shown in the example at the bottom of [this](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/selectorSyntax.html) page, I have been creating them like this:

```
$("div.container").jqplot(dataSeries1, dataSeries2, options);
```

However, I want to use a data renderer, reading from a JSON file.

So how should the above incantation be modified to allow this? I know how data renderers work, but all the [examples](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/data-renderers.html) involve returning a data series for a single plot. Is it even possible to use a renderer with multiple plots? Simply returning [ dataSeries1, dataSeries2 ] doesn't work. I guess given that the signature for a renderer is

```
function(userData, plotObject, options) { ... return data }
```

It can only ever apply to a single plot at a time.